# Unable to reply to comments directly

Tags: feature-request, comments, comment-replies

We can't reply to a comment directly, There must be a reply option under each comments, So that if you want to reply to a comment, you click on that option, rather than commenting again!.
(for example: See facebook)

Comment: What do you mean there 'must' be a reply option? Why? What purpose is this fulfilling?

Comment: @JonW It called evolution!.

Comment: Looking through the different evolved species on this planet, not a single one has a "reply" organ.

Comment: @Achmed more like devolution....

Comment: @Oded There is no such thing as an evolved or devolved species. All species have evolved from a common ancestor, so they have all evolved for the same amount of time. There is no "stronger" or "more fit", just "well-suited to the surroundings". So a species would evolve a "reply" organ if their environment preferred individuals with a reply organ, given the developmental cost of growing one. So we just need to create an environment that heavily favors an organ specific to replying. I'd say our current one does not meet that description.

Answer (score 4):

You can @ reply to people. Just type the `@` symbol followed by the first letter(s) of the person you're replying to and their username will appear ready to be clicked. Or you can just type their name after the @ in full.

But regardless, this isn't a discussion forum. It's not a place for comments and discussions, it's for Questions and Answers. Comments are secondary so shouldn't have complex UI and interactions. Just the bare minimum is needed so people can get their query across but without encouraging extended discussion. This isn't Facebook, so we shouldn't try to emulate it.

Comment: number of comments here, are not less than facebook!. you can check every question is full of waste comments and with a reply option you can avoid that.

Comment: Nope, what you are suggesting, @Achmed will only *increase* the number of "waste comments".

Comment: @Achmed "every question" is an exaggeration... and then there are some users who are confused why they *don't* get any comments...